# advertisement in flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a task to display advertisement in my FLEX mobile applicaiton. I am ussing flash builder 4.5.1
I have read 1-2 blog on internet but it wont work for me.

I f any one can help me than please!

Comment: What have you read?  Why won't it work for you?  What ad do you want to display?  How do you want to display it in relation to the rest of your application?  I don't think you've provided nearly enough information.

Comment: I have referred this for URL http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmedia/2011/05/displaying-ads-in-your-mobile-air-application/ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac-7b2e067c12e72dd6960-8000 http://alainthibodeau.com/blog/?p=147 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS901d38e593cd1bac3ef1d28412ac57b094b-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac-7b2e067c12e72dd6960-8000

Answer (score 0):

Check out these 2 step-by-step tutorials

iOS: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/iad-ane-ios.html

Android: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html